# Does the limit $e^{H_{n+1}}$-$e^{H_n}$ exists when $n\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{e^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+1}}-e^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}}$$

I see that it's an indeterminate form ($\infty-\infty$). I tried to factor and I got:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{e^{\frac{2}{n+1}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{n+1}}+1}\cdot e^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Now it's $0\cdot \infty$. How can we approach this type of problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It may help that $\log (n+1)<H_n < 1+\log n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$e^{H_{n+1}}-e^{H_n}=n(e^{1/(n+1)}-1)e^{(H_n-\ln n)}$$

If you need a further hint, try [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

Comment: Thank you. I did the computations and I obtained $-e^\gamma$. It's correct?

Comment: @DanielC. The sign is wrong but the result is correct.

Comment: @DanielC, that's what I got.  (Oops, I didn't notice the negative sign.  Thank you, Claude.)

Comment: Just to reinforce Claude's point, the harmonic sum increases with $n$, and $e^x$ is an increasing function, so the answer can't be negative.